# PHP/MySQL Sanitation Issue

Tags: php, mysql, sanitization

From LDAP I'm querying my users and this code sets them as a variable in the quoted format I need to run the MySQL query which would be 'username','other_username', etc...

```
            foreach ($prefs as $who => $pref) {
                    if (strpos($who, 'public') === false) {
                            $team_users_string .='\'' . $who . '\',';
                    }
```

When I try to sanitize the command with the following code it converts the string to \'username\',\'other_username\', what can I do to correct this?

```
    $team_users = rtrim($team_users_string, ",");

            $start_date = $_POST['start_year'] . '-' . $_POST['start_month'];
            $end_date = $_POST['end_year'] . '-' . $_POST['end_month'];

            echo 'Welcome, <strong>' . $user . '</strong><br />';
            echo '<br />';

            echo '<strong>Selected Start Date:</strong> ' . $start_date . '<br />';
            echo '<strong>Selected End Date:</strong> ' . $end_date . '<br />';

                  mysql_real_escape_string($team_users),
                  mysql_real_escape_string($start_date),
                  mysql_real_escape_String($end_date));

            $query = "SELECT * FROM vacation WHERE user_name in ($team_users) AND day BETWEEN '$start_date-01' AND '$end_date-31'";
```

Comment: That is what sanitizing does, it delimits the characters that could possibly cause a sql statement to be manipulated. Not sure what your question is.

Comment: That's not "sanitizing". That's escaping for SQL. sanitization is removing anything you don't want. The escape backslashes will be REMOVED by the database before stuffing the data into the table, and you'lll have just a literal `'foo','bar'` in your table, not the escaped version.

Comment: `mysql_query` should not be used in new applications. It's a deprecated interface that's being removed from future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). A guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) can help you keep current and avoid using out-of-date techniques. PDO and placeholders avoids this mess entirely.

Comment: Unfortunately we are using an older version of PHP and are not allowed to upgrade at this time.  The application is legacy and we are just trying to extract data from it.

Comment: Yeah I see a lot of people on SO berating anyone who posts about help with code using ext/mysql. But one has to assume there are millions of legacy PHP apps out there. They're simply not going to be rewritten, but we still need to do minor enhancements from time to time.

Comment: Much appreciated Bill, you rock!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you're adding the quote characters before you pass the string to mysql_real_escape_string(). So the literal quotes become escaped by that function.

You could avoid this by using mysql_real_escape_string(), and then delimiting the result in quotes.

Also I'd use an array and implode() the array to get commas, instead of being forced to rtrim() the last comma.

```
foreach ($prefs as $who => $pref) {
    if (strpos($who, 'public') === false) {
        $team_users_array[] = "'" . mysql_real_escape_string($who) . "'";
    }
}
$team_users = implode(",", $team_users_array); // no rtrim needed
```

Comment: I'm using an older version of PHP but this did work inserting the sanitation inside the array variable as you stated.  Thanks!